# Unable to get filtered bandpass signal in matlab

Tags: matlab, filter, fft, lowpass-filter, bandpass-filter

I'm trying to extract the signal with `15hz(bandpass filter)` component but not getting answer.However I could get the `10hz(lowpass filter)`.

I have 3 signals of three different frequencies `10 15 and 30hz` respectively.

I've designed them as follows:

```
x=0:1/fs:1;
f1=10;
f2=15;
f3=30;
s1=sin(2*pi*f1*x);
s2=sin(2*pi*f2*x);
s3=sin(2*pi*f3*x);
```

Now I've added all of them...

```
s=s1+s2+s3;
```

I've got correct fourier transform:

[image: Combined signal Fourier transform]

Butter command is not working here

This is what I've tried:

```
[b,a]=butter(10,[12 18]/500); % 500 is fs/2
filtered=filter(b,a,s);
```

I'm getting the following for filtered:

[image: Filtered Original]

Its fourier transform is this :

[image: Fourier transform of filtered signal]

I'm not even able to guess why I'm getting a peak at `0`

If it is lowpass I'm getting a perfect output:

```
[b,a]=butter(10,10/500);
filtered=filter(b,a,s);
```

[image: Low pass output]

What is reason behind this ? Please tell me whether there is another approach to solve this..Thankyou :)

**EDIT:**

This is complete code :

```
clc;
close all;
fs=1000;
x=0:1/fs:1;
f1=10;
f2=15;
f3=30;
s1=sin(2*pi*f1*x);
s2=sin(2*pi*f2*x);
s3=sin(2*pi*f3*x);
s=s1+s2+s3;
figure
x_axis=linspace(-fs/2,fs/2,numel(x));
plot(s)
fourier=fft(s);
answer=fftshift(fourier);
plot(x_axis,abs(answer));
figure
[b,a]=butter(10,10/500);
filtered=filter(b,a,s);
plot(filtered);
figure
plot(x_axis,abs(fftshift(fft(filtered))));
```

Comment: show how you do everything, including the plots

Comment: ok just give me a sec..I will edit the answer

Comment: @AnderBiguri I've posted the entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **tenth** order Butterworth is wayyy too big here (and in general). If you look at the filter coefficients `b`, you’ll see they’re on the order of machine precision (i.e., ~`1e-16`). Start with a second or third-order Butterworth filter! See if `butter(2, 10/500)` gives sufficient attenuation and *carefully* increase the filter order from there.